# Trying to pull all the values that matches the key into one key

Tags: python

I've been trying to simply just pull all the values that matches the key into one key. I can't wrap my head around on how to do this. Please help.

```
list_dir = ['192586_Sample_010_Test.pdf', '192586_Sample_020_Test.pdf', '192586_Sample_050_Test.pdf', '192120_Sample_020_Test.pdf', '192120_Sample_050_Test.pdf', '192163_Sample_010_Test.pdf', '192163_Sample_020_Test.pdf', '192145_Sample_010_Test.pdf', '192145_Sample_020_Test.pdf', '192145_Sample_050_Test.pdf', '192051_Sample_010_Test.pdf', '192051_Sample_020_Test.pdf', '192051_Sample_050_Test.pdf']
dict = {}

match = []
for i in list_dir:
    match.append((i.split("_", 1)[-2]))

for i in match:
    for x in list_dir:
        if i in x:
            dict[i] = list_dir

print(dict)
```

Output I'm looking for is

```
{'192586': '192586_Sample_010_Test.pdf', '192586_Sample_020_Test.pdf', '192586_Sample_050_Test.pdf', 
'192120': '192120_Sample_020_Test.pdf', '192120_Sample_050_Test.pdf', 
'192163': '192163_Sample_010_Test.pdf', '192163_Sample_020_Test.pdf', 
'192145': '192145_Sample_010_Test.pdf', '192145_Sample_020_Test.pdf', '192145_Sample_050_Test.pdf', 
'192051': '192051_Sample_010_Test.pdf', '192051_Sample_020_Test.pdf', '192051_Sample_050_Test.pdf'}
```

Comment: What do you want the output of your program to be?

Comment: `print(dict)` is generally a bad idea. if you comment out all the code above, this still runs fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just extract the key from the string and check if it's in the dict or not. If so append to the list otherwise create a new list.

Like this:

```
dct = {}

for i in list_dir:
    key = i.split("_")[0]
    
    if key in dct:
        dct[key].append(i)
    else:
        dct[key] = [i]

print(dct)
```

Comment: using a `dict` as var name is bad idea

Comment: Yes you are correct, I copied the code from the question. I'll edit it.